# Find the interval and radius of convergence of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Determine the radius and interval of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{4^n\ln(n)}$$

We apply the ratio test, thus

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}\ln(n+1)}}{\frac{x^{n}}{4^{n}\ln(n)}} \bigg| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg|\frac{x\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)4} \bigg| = |x| \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/4 < 1$$

So $|x| < 4$?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Have you tested the endpoints for the interval of convergence ? Common error to forget about it.

Comment: You need to check $x=4$, $x=-4$ also.

Comment: The root test seems to be the more natural route here and gives immediately $$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{4^n\,\log(n)}\right|}=\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt[n]{|\log(n)|}}\to |x/4|$$

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test gives the limit $L=\frac{|x|}{4}$.

so, $|x|<4 \implies L<1 \implies $ the series converges.

and

$|x|>4 \implies L>1 \implies $ the series diverges.

thus the radius of convergence is $R=4$.

> at $x=4$

- $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=0$
- $n\mapsto \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ is decreasing, so by alternate series criterion, it converges.

> at $x=-4$.

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt{n}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=+\infty$

$\implies \sqrt{n}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}>1 $ for large enough $n$

$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$

$\implies \sum \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the radio that is 4, so

$$|x|<4$$
Result in

$$-4<x<4$$

Then you have the interval $(-4,4)$, and now you need to evaluate in the serie to know if the interval would change in order to be open or close.

Evaluate for $x=-4$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\cdot(-4)^n\over 4^n\cdot ln(n)} \qquad Diverges$$

And evaluate for $x=4$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\cdot(4)^n\over 4^n\cdot ln(n)} \qquad Converges$$

Now, the intervals for the serie are $(-4,4]$